# Логирование параметров POST запроса в Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Каким образом можно включить логирование всех параметров (тела) приходящих `POST` запросов в `Tomcat`?

Сейчас в логе просто выводится тип запроса, но как включить отображение тела этих запросов?

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2017:22:43:44 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 306
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2017:22:43:44 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 306
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [12/Dec/2017:22:43:44 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 306
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2017:22:43:56 +0300] "POST /ws HTTP/1.1" 200 417
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
 private final String body;
 public MyRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
   super(request);
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
   try {
     InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
     if (inputStream != null) {
       bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
       char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
       int bytesRead = -1;
       while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
         stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
       }
     } else {
       stringBuilder.append("");
     }
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       throw ex;
   } finally {
     if (bufferedReader != null) {
       try {
         bufferedReader.close();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
         throw ex;
       }
     }
   }
   body = stringBuilder.toString();
 }

 @Override
 public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
   final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
   ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
     public int read() throws IOException {
       return byteArrayInputStream.read();
     }
   };
   return servletInputStream;
 }

 @Override
 public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
   return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
 }

 public String getBody() {
   return this.body;
 }
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    LOG.debug("payload: " + requestWrapper.getRequestBody());
}
```

`web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.host.PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PayloadLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528628/logging-payload-of-posts-to-tomcat)